# PHP: Sql query return true but have 0 columns

Tags: php, mysql

So I got one function on PHP with 2 sql querys, the problem is that the second one it's not working and I don't know why.

```
<?php
     include('../dbFunctions.php');
     function getName($id) {
        $connection = connectDB();

        $sql = mysqli_prepare($connection, "SELECT * FROM lugar_concreto WHERE idLugar = ?");
        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($sql, "s", $id);

        $query = $sql->execute();

        if(!$query)
                die();

        $result = $sql->store_result();

        $realresult = $sql->bind_result($id, $param1, $param2, $param3);

        $sql->fetch();

        if($sql->num_rows() == 0) {
            $sql2 = mysqli_prepare($connection, "SELECT * FROM lugar_transporte WHERE idLugarTte = ?");
            mysqli_stmt_bind_param($sql2, "s", $id);

            $query2 = $sql2->execute();

            if(!$query2)
                    die();

            $result2 = $sql2->store_result();

            $realresult2 = $sql2->bind_result($id, $param1, $param2, $param3);

            $sql2->fetch();

            $rawdata = array();
            $correct = $query2;
            $rawdata['param1'] = utf8_encode($param1);
            if(utf8_encode($param2) != null)
                    $rawdata['param2'] = utf8_encode($param2);
            $rawdata['param3'] = utf8_encode($param3);
            $rawdata['correct'] = $correct;

        } else {

            $rawdata = array();
            $correct = $query;
            $rawdata['param1'] = utf8_encode($param1);
            $rawdata['param2'] = utf8_encode($param2);
            $rawdata['param3'] = utf8_encode($param3);
            $rawdata['correct'] = $correct;
        }

        disconnectDB($connection);
        return $rawdata;

        }
?>
```

I prepare and execute one query and if it return empty result (0 rows), then I execute the other query, I know it's now the clear and efficient way but it should work I think.

The problem is that I've used `var_dump()` with the vars inside the big if, like `$query`, `$result`, `$realresult` and all of them returned `bool(true)`, but after the `$sql->fetch();` the var `$sql` has 0 num_rows, I don't know why.

I use php 5 I don't know if have something to do with this.

If any of you know a better way to do this please tell me, any help will be apreciated!

EDIT: this is what it looks the var `$sql2` with `var_dump()`:

[image: var_dump($sql2)]

Comment: Note: The object-oriented interface to `mysqli` is significantly less verbose, making code easier to read and audit, and is not easily confused with the obsolete `mysql_query` interface. Before you get too invested in the procedural style it’s worth switching over. Example: `$db = new mysqli(…)` and `$db->prepare("…")` The procedural interface is an artifact from the PHP 4 era when `mysqli` API was introduced and should not be used in new code.

Comment: Somewhat personal preference, somewhat actually helpful, I suggest explicitly listing the fields that you're selecting.  Not only does it make it clear for future readers of your code, but should you add fields in the future, it also ensures that you get the expected number of columns returned.

Comment: Your title doesn't seem to match the problem. Your problem is with `num_rows` from the first query, not the second query.

Comment: No, the first query works fine and the `num_rows` too, the problem is with the second query, which have 0 columns, I've seen it with `var_dump($sql)` inside the if

Comment: @DavidZam `num_rows()` is _not_ a function.  You can test this by passing an id that should produce a row from the first query.  You will find that you _still_ get inside the `if`, even though there are not 0 rows.

Comment: @PatrickQ you're right, I've removed the () but the second query still returned 0 columns I don't know why

Comment: I suggest that you don't re-use variable names like you are.  I'm not sure how the mysqli library handles `bind_result()` when there are no rows returned, but I'd say there's a good chance that `$id` is being set to some falsey value (FALSE, NULL, '', etc).  So instead of being the value passed in to the function (which is probably what you're expecting), it very well could be getting wiped out.

Comment: I've changed the name of the vars for `bind_result()` and still not working...I've added a picture with the content of the `$sql2` var, that's why I know that has 0 rows.

Comment: I'm talking about the fact that you're doing `$realresult = $sql->bind_result($id, $param1, $param2, $param3);` and then `mysqli_stmt_bind_param($sql2, "s", $id);`  If you have changed either of those, please update your code above to reflect that.

Comment: THAT WAS THE PROBLEM! I LOVE YOU MAN! @PatrickQ thank you so much! I've fixed saving `$id` in a temp var and using it on the second `mysqli_stmt_bind_param()` method, thank you!!